# Pack the whole solution into a single nupkg?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a number of helper libraries that I would like to turn into a single NuGet package:

```
ProjectA
ProjectB (references ProjectA)
ProjectC
```

I can make *individual* packages of these:

```
nuget pack ProjectA.nuspec
nuget pack ProjectB.nuspec
nuget pack ProjectC.nuspec
```

Or I can "bundles" of referencing projects:

```
nuget pack ProjectB.nuspec -IncludeReferencedProjects
nuget pack ProjectC.nuspec
```

But I'd very much like a *single* .nupkg file containing *all* the projects.

Is this possiblie to achieve?

-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a "bundling project" that only references the other projects:

```
ProjectA
ProjectB (references ProjectA)
ProjectC
ProjectD (references ProjectA, ProjectB and ProjectC)
```

With this in place, I can pack everything into a single NuGet package.

```
nuget pack ProjectD.nuspec -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

Not super elegant to achieve, but it kind of makes sense to have a neutral project without its own functionality to bundle up the other diverse projects.